# How to open fragment from RecyclerView Adapter?

Tags: android, fragment, adapter

I would like to pass data from adapter to my fragment, 
so basically when i try to click an item, The fragment should open,
but, my app did nothing.
so how can i solve this?

**Adapter**

```
public class CatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CatAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static String TAG = "Cat Adapter";

    private ArrayList<String> catUrlImage = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> cuteCatName = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context catContext;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener listenerthis;


    public CatAdapter(ArrayList<String> catUrlImage, ArrayList<String> cuteCatName, Context catContext, OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener listener) {
        this.catUrlImage = catUrlImage;
        this.cuteCatName = cuteCatName;
        this.catContext = catContext;
        this.listenerthis = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_item, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder catViewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);


        return catViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnBinding: called");

        Glide.with(catContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(catUrlImage.get(position))
                .into(viewHolder.catImage);

        viewHolder.catName.setText(cuteCatName.get(position));

        viewHolder.catItemLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(catContext, cuteCatName.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                listenerthis.onClick(position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return catUrlImage.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CircleImageView catImage;
        TextView catName;
        RelativeLayout catItemLayout;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            catImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iLikeCat);
            catName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.catVeryCuteName);
            catItemLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_container);

        }
    }

    public interface OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener{
        void onClick(int parameter);
    }

}
```

i already change my Activity before the post so it more changing the onRecycleViewOnItemClickListener

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements CatAdapter.OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener{
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private ArrayList<String> catArray = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> catArrayImageUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    DataCat dataCat = new DataCat();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter rAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager rLayoutManager;
    GalleryFragment galleryFragment = new GalleryFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "Cat Has Create OnCreated");
        findView();
        initView();
        catData();
    }

    private void catData() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Preparing A Bitmap for a Cat");
        for (int i = 0; i < dataCat.catUrl.length; i++) {
           catArrayImageUrl.add(dataCat.catUrl[i]);
           catArray.add(dataCat.catName[i]);
        }

        initRecycleView();

    }

    private void initRecycleView() {
        CatAdapter catAdapter = new CatAdapter(catArrayImageUrl, catArray, this, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(catAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void findView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "initRecylce Vieq");
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewList);
        rLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void initView() {

    }

    @Override
    public void initListener() {
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(int parameter) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container_galery, galleryFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
    }
}
```

I input some layout maybe there some bad structure on my layout

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_galery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

i've already try the solutions from the comment bellow and my fragment still not showing up. I didnt get any error from my logCat, when i try to click.

Comment: You get a nullPointerException , right  ? you haven't initialized your listener

Comment: I already change it and initialize the listener but, still no news from fragment, my fragment still not showing up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do two small changes in your code-

**Adapter**

```
public CatAdapter(ArrayList<String> catUrlImage, ArrayList<String> cuteCatName, Context catContext, OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener listenerthis) {
    this.catUrlImage = catUrlImage;
    this.cuteCatName = cuteCatName;
    this.catContext = catContext;
    this.listenerthis = listenerthis;
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
private void initRecycleView() {
    CatAdapter catAdapter = new CatAdapter(catArrayImageUrl, catArray, this, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(catAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}
```

thats it. Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: the fragment didnt open up, and i got no error from log cat, why?

Answer (score 1):

try below code for call fragment from adapter. in  this code i have call fragment from recylerview adapter.

**Code**

```
myholder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    FragmentManager manager=((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction Ft=manager.beginTransaction();
    Ft.replace(R.id.container_fl,new ProfileFragment());

    Ft.commit();
}
```

});

please check your fragment support **android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity**

try this:

```
((AppCompatActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager()
```

and support: **support.v4.app.FragmentManager**
try this :

```
FragmentManager manager = ((Activity)context).getFragmentManager();
```

or

```
((AppCompatActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager()
```

this code is work for me .

Answer (score 0):

Your interface/listener is not initialized , it's null.

You have to implement the click method from your activity in which you initialized your adapter and set a value to your listener "listenerThis".

Create a setter for the listener in your adapter :

```
  public void setOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener(OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener listener){
        listenerthis=listener;
    }
```

and in your activity implement the listener:

```
 adapter.setOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener(new OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener(int parameter){

@override OnClick(int Parameter){
//do whatever you want with that parameter.

})
```

Comment: its still not work, i've already implement that in adapter and put it on main activity, but still didnt open up my fragment

Comment: Have you tried to debug ? have you tried to check if it works without the click event (by putting the fragment transaction code inside Activity.onCreate) ?